# how to bind a datagrid to a devexpress comboBox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid, devexpress, aspxcombobox

ok folks  i have a populated datagrid and my comboBox is populated all i need now is the knowledge on how  to bind the datagrid to my AspxcomboBox

i have done research on this i find precious little that makes sense to me in my situation. 
if you guys need to see my code i will provide it but i would rather not if possible.Just to clarify i did do research on this so i am not just asking for comfort-sake or convenience.  i knew how to do this once upon a time but vb has ruined me any help or advice would be appreciated i am asking for assistance so keep the votedowns to a minimum

Comment: We will need some more information at the very least... code would be easier. You can change field names etc if necessary. How are you binding data to the grid? I assume that the combo box is there add a filter to the data.

Comment: @Mych you are correct this will act as a filter for the data in the grid .THe data in the grid is retrieved from sql   do you still require some code i apologize i normally would give you my whole app but this is a sensitive situation

Comment: OK are you using a SQLDataSource control to populate the datagrid or are you doing this using other methods in the codebehind?

Comment: other methods  a stored procedure namely the old fashioned way open the connection call procedure                                  BindGrid(New ExecQueryArgs("DB", "PROC", Params), DataGrid2)

Comment: How are you passing the filter element into the SP?

Comment: filter element basically just select the column that will be used to filter and group the items by colummn from my table i just need to link the two , then i am set. i can then turn my attention to the real flesh of the app, i feel like a idiot for asking about this i know in the past that it was simple

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this... it has a simple layout and uses a dropdown rather than combo but can be adapted. If you run into any problems then let us know.... but supplying some code would be easier.

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Filter-GridView-with-DropDownList-using-FilterExpression-in-SqlDataSource-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: thank you mych i will have a look ,i appreciate the help

Comment: No problem... I found this link by just putting Filter Gridview Combo and google gave me an option for Filter Gridview Dropdown. There was even links for having dropdowns in the header of each column.

Comment: i already whent through this page hahaha but thanks all the same i think i should just rest then tackle this ,a bit over worked i also set a bounty accidentally(thought i could just call it off wanted to see how it works) no clue how to get my rep back

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the steps:
1- Define a asp:ObjectDataSource ID="**dgDataSource**" for your datagrid.
2- Define a asp:ObjectDataSource ID="**cbDataSource**" for your ComboBox.
NOTE: Each of these 2 data sources are connected to a 2 different Models.

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="myListGridView" ClientInstanceName="myListGridView" DataSourceID="dgDataSource"
    runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" KeyFieldName="**field1Ofdg**"
    OnRowUpdated="myListGridView_RowUpdated">

<Columns>
    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="**field1Ofdg**" Caption="Code" Width="30%" >
        </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="**field2Ofdg**" ReadOnly="false" >  
        <PropertiesComboBox DataSourceID="cbDataSource" TextField="**LabelOfcb**" ValueField="**IdOfcb**"  >
        </PropertiesComboBox>
    </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>                   
</Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

thes are the definitions for your data sources:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="dgDataSource" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetMyDataForGridFunction" 
        UpdateMethod="UpdateDataForGridFunction" TypeName="namespace1"></asp:ObjectDataSource>

     <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="cbDataSource" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetMyDataForComboBoxFunction"
         TypeName="namespace2"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

NOTE: **field1Ofdg** and **field1Ofdg** are properties of **Model1** Model of the grid.
**LabelOfcb** and **IdOfcb** are properties of **Model2** model of the ComboBox.

Keep me updated if it works fine to you :)

Best Regards,
ANDOURA